# Display incoming xml request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, post

Hey guys,
Is there an easy way to display the complete xml request I'm getting posted to one of my methods?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question , but you can have access of every request to ActionController by the request method , in your action you could render it by render(:text => request.inspect)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the actual XML that is being posted rather than a params hash try

`xml_data = request.raw_post`

Then to get a hash out of that you could do

`hash_from_xml_data = Hash.from_xml(xml_data)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring a bit, but you probably want `request.body`.

An easy, though slightly dirty, way to view it is to raise it as an error in your controller: `raise request.body`